# When rendering lists in React, should I always be giving elements a `key` or can I spread the array?

Tags: reactjs

[React tells us](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key) why it's important for lists to have keys when they're being rendered, and this makes sense for actual lists of data.

However, for example, we sometimes end up with arrays of components as props.

Assume we have the following component `MyForm` which takes an `actions` prop which is an array of components, and we'll assume each component in the array doesn't have a `key` prop:

```js
const MyForm: FunctionComponent<{ actions: ReactNode[] }> = ({ actions }) =>
  ...
    <div className="actions">
      {actions}
    </div>
  ...
```

`actions` is only ever going to be a small collection of buttons like `Yes`/`No`.

`MyForm` as it is will render with warnings since we're rendering a list and its items don't have a `key`.

There are two things we could do:

- Give each item in the array a key
- Spread the array (`{...actions}`)

Both options get rid of the warning, but my question is whether spreading arrays here like this is okay in some scenarios or if we should be giving items in an array a `key`?

I can see arguments both ways, since on one hand we've got a list and should try and use it like a list properly.

On the other hand, it's not really a list. If `actions` wasn't a prop but something defined within `MyForm` and it was just two buttons `Yes` and `No` then we'd almost certainly render them as two consecutive buttons and not an array of buttons. We're also not going to do list-y things to the array such as sort it or modify it as mentioned in the [React docs](https://react.dev/learn/rendering-lists#keeping-list-items-in-order-with-key)

I'm interested in what others think about this - are there classes of lists where we can ignore needing a `key` and just spread the array when rendering it?

Comment: I'm getting an error `Spread children are not supported in React.`

Comment: Can you use `ReactNode` instead of `ReactNode[]` for your actions? You can wrap multiple elements with `<></>`

Comment: [This StackBlitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/key-demo-zbvegp?file=src%2FApp.tsx%3AL20-L20&terminal=dev) should work for playing with it

Comment: Using a `ReactNode` and wrapping the props in a fragment does work, and maybe in scenarios like this it's a better alternative? I feel like it signals intent better, though I am still interested in knowing if there are drawbacks to just spreading an array and if people have experiences with it

Comment: There are also benefits to keeping a `ReactNode[]`, such as being able to `.map` in order to wrap components and so on before spreading the array, though that's just me theorising, I'd be interested in hearing about real world examples too if there are any

Answer (score 2):

According to the official way, `key` is definitely essential, and using `map` to render the array out and distribute the `key` is probably the best way for the job.

Therefore, I would still use `map` to loop through the array and wrap each item with any generic wrapper (`<div>` for block, `<span>` for inline) and individually assign the `key` for each child like so --

```
  <div className="card">
    {paragraphs.map((a, i) => {
      return <div key={i}>{a}</div>;
    })}
  </div>
```

See the code in action (copied your example)

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-albattani-6ddnkr?file=/src/App.tsx:127-237

In the end, you can pick whatever approach you think fits best according to your needs, as long as it meets the requirements of the feature. Having `key` for each item -- like the official doc said -- is good in general especially when you are trying to re-order or re-sort the list. If you know your list aren't going to do those, you can probably get away with just the idea you brought up.

Comment: You can use `React.Fragment` instead of `div`